# python schedule package with init function

Tags: python, schedule

I need to create a init function, which needs to run before the scheduler starts. I am using the schedule package.

Is there an easy way to add an init function, which runs before the scheduler starts.

```
import schedule 
def call_me(): 
  print("I am invoked")
schedule.every(1).seconds.do(call_me)
while True: 
  schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: Why not add `call_me()` before the line `schedule.every(1).seconds.do(call_me)`?

Comment: Thants it what i am searching for. Thank you. Can you add your comment as response that i can prove it

Comment: Happy to help. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly invoke the function before using `schedule`:

```py
call_me()
schedule.every(1).seconds.do(call_me)
# ...
```